# How to loop through unknown json keys with jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I have a simple JSON object, but the problem is that the key can change which means I can't call the data with its key name. My aim is to present the data in a table layout.

This is one example of how I get the data:

```
[{"domain":"animals","country":"Argentina"}]
```

But it can also be that I get this result

```
[{"fruits":"apple","country":"Argentina", "value": "1234"}]
```

Now I could find out how to get the keys:

```
var dataKeys = []
for( var key in data[ 0 ] ) {
  dataKeys.push( key );
  console.log(key);
}
```

Very well, now I have the names for the columns.
But from here I have no clue how to get the values to each key.

```
var dataKeys = []
for( var key in data[ 0 ] ) {
  dataKeys.push( key );
  //console.log(key);
}
//console.log(result.join());
for( var x in data ) {
   for (var i in dataKeys) {
      console.log(data[dataKeys[i]]);
   };
}
```

But the console shows "undefined".

Answer (score 1):

You have to consider the index variable `x` in the loop.

```
for( var x in data ) {
   for (var i in dataKeys) {
      console.log(data[x][dataKeys[i]]);
   };
}
```

on a related note, the keys can be achieved by

```
dataKeys = Object.keys(data[0])
```

also

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if i am not wrong-

```
var json = '[{"domain":"animals","country":"Argentina"},   {"fruits":"apple","country":"Argentina", "value": "1234"}]';
var data= JSON.parse(json);
$.each(data,function(key,val){
    alert("Main object at Index: "+ key);
    $.each(val,function(i,v){
        alert(i + ': ' + v);
    });
});
```

Live demo : [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/sharif084/PwY36/)